# How can I import SCSS modules in React-Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, node-sass, sass-modules

I am trying to import **styles** from **Navbar.module.scss** file in my **Navbar.tsx** component.
[image]

But it says
[image]

I have already installed **node-sass** and **@types/node-sass** packages.
Here's my package.json :
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I just installed this package called **[typed-scss-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-scss-modules)**
and it generated the type declarations for all the  **scss** files in my src directory.

> yarn add -D typed-scss-modules
>
> yarn typed-scss-modules src

Then I imported my scss modules like so:

> import styles from './Navbar.modules.scss';

And everything worked so well.

Answer (score 0):

There is easier way, just add the d.ts file or text to exist file next line

```
declare module "*.module.scss";
```

End this should solve the problem.