# How to get correctly typed scss modules?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, sass, eslint

I'm trying to use SCSS modules in Typescript project. I can't figure out how to type SCSS modules.

This is code snippet that works as expected, component renders with styles.

```
import * as classes from './button.module.scss';

export const Button = () => (
<button className={classes.base}>Ok</button>
);
```

When I define scss module like this

```
declare module "*.module.scss";
```

`tsc --noEmit` successful completes but lint complains

```
error  Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `ClassValue`  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
error  Unsafe member access .base on an `any` value                                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

I've also tried like this

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const classes: Record<string, string>;
  export default classes;
}
```

then `tsc --noEmit` reports

```
TS2339: Property 'base' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.scss")'.
```

and eslint has one error

```
Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `ClassValue`  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
```

I'd like not to disable any of reported eslint rules.
I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379576/how-can-i-import-scss-modules-in-react-typescript) but it requires additional lib to generate types from scss files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356082/6463558

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin provides type information to IDEs and eslint/tsc can't use that information since TypeScript does not support plugins during compilation. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in our codebase:

```
// types.d.ts

declare module '*.module.scss' {
  const styles: { [className: string]: string };
  export default styles;
}
```

(This is equivalent to the code you showed except `*.scss` has been changed to `*.module.scss`.)

Then, in your `.tsx` files:

```
import styles from './MyComponent.module.scss';
```

Note that there is no `*` in the import.

If this import doesn't work, make sure you have `esModuleInterop: true` in `tsconfig.json`. Setting this property to true is considered best practice, and it is the default value when creating a new TSConfig via `tsc --init`.

If you want stricter typing, there is the [typed-scss-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-scss-modules) npm package.